# How to sandbox students' Python 3 code submissions for automatic assignment evaluation on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10, sandbox

I am the TA for a coding class in which students will have to write Python 3 scripts to solve programming problems. An assignment consists of several problems, and for each problem the student is supposed to write a python program that will read input from standard input and write the output to the standard output. And for each problem there will be hidden test cases that we will use to evaluate their codes and grade them accordingly. So the idea is to automatize this process as much as possible. The problem is how to implement the whole framework to run students' assignments without compromising the safety of the system the assignments will be running on, which will probably be my laptop (which has Windows 10). I need to set up some kind of sandbox for Python 3, establishing limits for execution time, memory usage, disallowing access to the file system, networking, limiting imports only to safe modules from Python's standard library, etc.

Conceptually speaking I would like some kind of sand-boxed service that can receive a python script + some tests cases, the service runs the python script against the test cases in a safe environment (detecting compilation errors, time limit exceeded errors, memory limit exceeded errors, attempts to use forbidden libraries, etc.) and reporting the results back. So from Windows I can simply write a simple script that iterates over all students submissions and uses this service as a black-box to evaluate them.

Is anything like that possible on Windows 10? If so, how? My educated guess is that something like Docker or a Virtual Machine might be useful, but to be honest I'm not really sure because I lack enough expertise in these technologies, so I'm open to any suggestions.

Any advises on how to set up a secure system for automatic evaluation of untrusted Python 3 code submissions will be very appreciated.

Comment: If you install a standalone linux VM in your laptop and configure it appropriately, you can script the upload of students scripts into virtualenvs with required libs and run unit tests against required APIs or gather some process stats. Or automate the script runs. If previously to the run you disable network in the VM there should be no harm to your system I think, you can reboot the VM and have limits on its memory use, cpu etc. Basically, in other words, don't run their work directly on your laptop/network. Don't know CMS but looks interesting for management.

Comment: Otherwise Python sandboxing looks difficult from a brief search of mine (I am not commenting docker here)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for a system that automatically evaluates a code using test cases.

You can use [CMS](https://cms-dev.github.io/index.html) to satisfy your use case. It is mainly a system to manage a programming contest, but it will be perfect for what you are trying to accomplish in your class.